# How to make dynamic content on a site with react and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am really new to react and node and I just finished a few courses and plan to make a blog but I don't want static webpages any ideas on how I can load the webpages from a database instead if it's possible?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You can use MongoDB & Express & React & Node.js to build your site, there should be many this kinds of course from google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are a bit confused by the many moving parts that websites with back-ends have.
If you were to create a blog you'd have to design your components before hand mostly based on how you planned your database and information flow on the back-end. So the components would be pre-designed just not filled in with information/content. Only after you have done the steps above you would pull information from your server using a Restful API that you'd create in your nodeJS back-end. I'll include a list with things you need to learn for your project.

Frontend:

React + Connecting to Restful API

Backend:

MySQL/no-SQL Database(MongoDB is a great No-SQL)

Creating a Restful API

Goodluck on your project

Comment: When you say how I planned the database can the database take in lengthy content like blog posts and if yes is there a limit to how many characters (words) it can handle?

Comment: Everything on the web uses databases. they are built to handle huge amounts of data, the only thing I would not recommend you put in a database is information/files that are not string based like images as that would be inefficient.